# StackApps Oauth Buttons Are White On White In Opera

Tags: bug, design, stackapps, opera

When I installed the [Inbox Extension](https://stackapps.com/q/2948/277) I had to use the Stack Apps Oauth.

Here is what I got:

[image: img]

Both buttons have no text, I had to set the mouse pointer over the button just to see what's going on.

Please add text to the buttons per default. Guessing games are bad. :)

Comment: An **Opera** user appears. It's somewhat sympathic

Comment: Possibly some jquery is trying to load before `$(document).ready()` . Possibly.